# Move files between two very 'different' locations in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, cygwin

I want to move files between two locations on the fly in Bash, but they are saved in two completely different places.

For example, if my first file is at:

```
C:/This/Folder/Is/At/A/Very/Different/Location/file.txt
```

And my second file is at:

```
C:/To/This/Folder/Which/Is/Somewhere/Else/Completely
```

And I essentially want to execute something like:

```
mv C:/This/Folder/Is/At/A/Very/Different/Location/file.txt C:/To/This/Folder/Which/Is/Somewhere/Else/Completely
```

But I am hoping to do it as I go, and don't really want to type out the whole file paths. I could copy and paste the file paths at each directory, but was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

My first impulse would be to navigate to the first folder, then save the current directory as a variable, then navigate to the second folder, save the current directory as a variable and do something like:

```
mv $firstFolder $secondFolder
```

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: @123: note the `cygwin` tag.

Comment: Do you use `tab` for auto completion?

Comment: I can use `tab` for autocompletion.

Comment: Are these always the same directories?

Comment: No, that's the thing. It will be a one off move from one to the other, so I don't want to write a script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
#!/bin/ksh
#store  your folder1 path in a variable 
folder1="C:/This/Folder/Is/At/A/Very/Different/Location/"

#store  your folder2 path in a variable 
folder2="C:/To/This/Folder/Which/Is/Somewhere/Else/Completely"

#store filename as input paramenter or hardcoded filename (as you like)
fileName="${1}" 
#fileName="myFileToMove.txt"

mv ${folder1}/${fileName} ${folder2}

#or mv ${folder2}/${fileName} ${folder1}
```

Regards

C

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but what if I don't want to write a script?

Comment: if you don't want to write a script you can store your path variable in your .bashrc file .. btw it would be easiest (in future) to change the path variable in a script than in into .bashrc file

Comment: OK, is there no way of navigating to one directory, saving that directory as a temporary variable in the session, navigating to the second directory, saving that as a temporary variable, and then using both of those?

Comment: you could do it like this i.e cd /tmp/myPath/123/456/; export tempFolder=$PWD; cd /tmp/myPath2/123/789/; export tempFolder2=$PWD; touch $tempFolder/fileName.txt; mv $tempFolder/fileName.txt $tempFolder2; ls -ltr $tempFolder $tempFolder2

Answer (score 0):

If the path to the folder names is sufficiently unique, you could use something like

```
mv C:/This/**/Location/file.txt C:/To/**/Completely
```

Needless to say that if a file named file.txt can be found along two differend source paths, you end up moving two files. Therefore I would either use -i or -n or -v with `mv`.